# Unable to import .css stylesheet in my JSX component

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I just imported .css stylesheet in my component and the problem occured in generated file, it causes error like require.js:5 Uncaught Error: Script error for "src/Container.css", needed by: Container

folder structure

```
App
    node-modules
    src
       Container.css
       Container.jsx
    dest
       Container.css
       Container.js
```

src - Container.jsx :

```
    import './Container.css';

    const Container = () => (
        <div className="block">  // i know that here i can use like {style.block} if I do like import style from './Container.css'; 
            <p className="message">Get started !!!</p>
        </div>
    );

    ReactDOM.render(<Container />, document.getElementById('App'));
```

Container.css :

```
.block {
        height: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 5px 5px -3px;
        background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        border-width: 1px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
        border-image: initial;
        padding: 15px;
}
.message {
        color: #413b3b;
        font-size: 18px;
}
```

I'm not sure how to import Container.css in my Container.jsx file and make it work and I'm using **grunt-babel to transpiling jsx to js** and require.js
.
So I am clearly stating that I'm **not using webpack** and css-modules. I know using css-modules is a wise way, but not sure how to  implement without webpack.

I have imported my css stylesheet in my component and it causes when I run my application.I have implemented inline styling that's works but i want to know is there's any better ways to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got solution still answering here, it will help some people who needs to work react with grunt and babel. If you need to import your css file in your component like

`import './Container.css';`

you need this plugin : https://github.com/guybedford/require-css

by using this you can import it like :

**`import 'css!./Button_Styles.css';`**

this answer for people who are using grunt and require , not webpack and css-modules.

Answer (score 0):

```
import containerStyles from './Container.css';
```

First Solution --->
Write inside render() -

```
let cls_block = `${containerStyles.block}`;
```

In html section-
    className={cls_block}

Second Solution --->
    className={containerStyles.block}

Comment: Implemented those ideas @PRADEEP, real problem is that container.css will look like container.css.js while running an app

Comment: Have you added css loders in babel config? If not, please add it. Find a sample below

module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader?localIdentName=' + cssModulesIdentName + '&modules&importLoaders=1&sourceMap!postcss-loader',
      }
  ]
}

Comment: If I have been use babelrc or webpack, I will definitely follow your ideas.
I am using grunt and require, tried adding require-css and it's working, Thanks for the help.